# Chrome icon for shortcut link

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Strange behaviour on Chrome:

If I create a desktop shortcut to my page using cog wheel -> More Tools -> Create shortcut I get the favicon on the shortcut

However, if I create a desktop shortcut to my page by dragging and dropping from the address bar, I get Chrome's default icon in the shortcut !

Is there a way to get my favicon on the shortcut also when dragging and dropping from the address bar ?

Comment: I see the same thing here. Also updated Chrome to newest version. Seems to be an anomaly with Chrome as I cannot even change the icon in the shortcut properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an operating system issue.  If you look at older Windows OS's, you'll note that they support the favicon.  The drag method creates an shortcut controlled by the OS, which in Windows goes by the Default App assigned to it's file-type.  The Chrome(ium) / Tools / Create Shortcut method creates a shortcut that is allowed control by the browser and is attached to the browser profile, as evidenced by the fact you cannot do so as Guest.